Enable/disable analytics for tracking push notifications after MarketingCloud SDK initialization? (Android)
MarketingCloud analytics for tracking push notifcations can be enabled by calling setAnalyticsEnabled(true) on the MarketingCloudConfig.builder() instance when initializing SFMCSdk, as explained here.
We would like to enable/disable analytics according to user consent for tracking, to make our app 100% GDPR compliant.
In our app user can update user consent multiple times, so is there a way to enable/disable MC analytics without reinitialising SDK?

Yes! We introduced a series of runtime toggles expressly for this use-case:
  SFMCSdk.requestSdk { sdk ->
    sdk.mp { push ->
      // Enable
      push.analyticsManager.enableAnalytics()
      
      // Disable
      push.analyticsManager.disableAnalytics()
    }
  }

The docs are being updated to include these code snippets and instructions.

This is working. Thank you!
